# Llamar a varias funciones en un evento onClick

Tags: reactjs

Tengo esta acción en un Click de botón en un componente que me cierra una modal en un componente primario.

```
 <button onClick={props.close}>
```

Me ejecuta la acción correctamente, sin embargo necesito pasar más funciones en el evento onClick en una función de flecha, algo de este estilo:

```
 <button
        onClick={() => {
           const funcion1 = props.close;
           const funcion2 = saludo("parametro");
           const funcion3 = hola(parametro);
        }}
      >
```

Pero en este caso deja de funcionar la accion props.close. Qué podría hacer? hay alguna alternativa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Actualización

En el ejemplo de la pregunta, se asignan funciones a otras variables, pero estas son solo las referencias, hace falta llamarlas para que se ejecuten:

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    //function expression
     const funcion1 = props.close;
     const funcion2 = saludo("parametro");
     const funcion3 = hola("parametro");
     //function call:ejecuta
     funcion1();
  }}
></button>
```

#### First class functions

Lo que se esta intentado codificar se conoce como [first class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function), es un concepto usado en functional programming, trata de lo siguiente:

- Una función pude ser enviada como argumento dentro de otra función.
- Una función puede regresar otra función.
- Una función puede ser asignada a otra variable.
- Una función se comporta como cualquier otro `tipo`.

JS nos permite usar **first class functions**, en esta pregunta se tiene un gran ejemplo y se pueden observar algunos de estos conceptos.

#### Una función puede ser enviada como argumento dentro de otra función:

```
<button onClick={()=>primarioHanlder(props.close, saludo, hola, ["param saludo", "param hola", "any param"])}>Click me</button>
```

#### Una función puede ser asignada a otra variable:

```
//asignamos las referencias a variables
    //para crear estructuras
    const funcion1 = fn;
    const funcion2 = saludo;
    const funcion3 = hola;
```

#### Una función se comporta como cualquier otro tipo:

```
 //muestra sus tipos y referencias
    console.log(typeof fn);
    console.log(fn);
    console.log(typeof fn2);
    console.log(fn2);
    console.log(typeof fn3);
    console.log(fn3);
```

Aquí, un ejemplo tratando de emular la situación que el colega @rafa_pe nos expone, nótese el **trailing closure** que se forma con la función `props.close` y también como las funciones enviadas como argumentos dentro de `primarioHanlder` pertenecen a scopes diferentes:

```js
function App(){

  function closeHandler(){
    console.log("in close handler")
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <Primario close={closeHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Primario(props){
  function primarioHanlder(fn, fn2, fn3, arrayParams){
    //JS nos permite pasar funciones como argumentos
    //a otras funciones
    console.log("en primario handler");
    //muestra sus tipos y referencias
    console.log(typeof fn);
    console.log(fn);
    console.log(typeof fn2);
    console.log(fn2);
    console.log(typeof fn3);
    console.log(fn3);
    console.log(arrayParams);
    //asignamos las referencias a variables
    //para crear estructuras
    const funcion1 = fn;
    const funcion2 = saludo;
    const funcion3 = hola;
    console.log("ejecucion de funciones first class, con parametros")
    //depende del programador 
    //como asignar los argumentos/parametros
    //trailing closure
    funcion1();
    funcion2(arrayParams[0]);
    funcion3(arrayParams[1]);

  }
  function saludo(any){
    console.log("en saludo", any);
  }
  function hola(any){
    console.log("en hola", any);
  }
  //return <button onClick={props.close}>First Class Functions in JS</button>
  return <button onClick={()=>primarioHanlder(props.close, saludo, hola, ["param saludo", "param hola", "any param"])}>First Class Functions in JS</button>
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

#### Notas de campo

1. En este caso como tú eres el diseñador, depende de ti que los agumentos sean asignados correctamente en los parametros de las funciones, esto una vez que tengas las funciones en **scope**.
2. En el ejemplo, se muestra el envÍo de un `array` de `params` como parte de los argumentos de la función `primarioHanlder`, y se decidió como asignar estos `params` a las funciones una vez dentro del scope de la misma.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, es edificante. Sin embargo props.close no me funciona cuando uso una función de flecha

Comment: @rafa_pe, actualize la respuesta con el caso que expones, lo que propuse es otra forma de manejarlo, es mas verbose, pero puede ser de ayuda en caso de que quieras estructurar el código o necesites manejar mas argumentos, dime si fue de ayuda,.

Comment: genial! esta vez sí, bien explicado lo de expression y call

Comment: Que buena pregunta @rafa_pe, suerte y salud.